# SQL Insert not considering blank values for the insert in my C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a nice piece of C# code which allows me to import data into a table with less columns than in the SQL table (as the file format is consistently bad).

My problem comes when I have a blank entry in a column. The values statement does not pickup an empty column from the csv. And so I receive the error

> You have more insert columns than values

Here is the query printed to a message box...

[image]

As you can see there is nothing for Crew members 4 to 11, below is the file...

[image]

Please see my code:

```
SqlConnection ADO_DB_Connection = new SqlConnection();
ADO_DB_Connection = (SqlConnection)
(Dts.Connections["ADO_DB_Connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

// Inserting data of file into table
int counter = 0;
string line;
string ColumnList = "";

// MessageBox.Show(fileName);

System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        ColumnList = "[" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "],[") + "]";
    }
    else
    {
        string query = "Insert into " + TableName + " (" + ColumnList + ") ";
        query += "VALUES('" + line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "')";

        // MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());

        SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, ADO_DB_Connection);
        myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    counter++;
}
```

If you could advise how to include those fields in the insert that would be great.

Here is the same file but opened with a text editor and not given in picture format...

```
Date,Flight_Number,Origin,Destination,STD_Local,STA_Local,STD_UTC,STA_UTC,BLOC,AC_Reg,AC_Type,AdultsPAX,ChildrenPAX,InfantsPAX,TotalPAX,AOC,Crew 1,Crew 2,Crew 3,Crew 4,Crew 5,Crew 6,Crew 7,Crew 8,Crew 9,Crew 10,Crew 11
05/11/2022,241,BOG,SCL,15:34,22:47,20:34,02:47,06:13,N726AV,"AIRBUS A-319                  ",0,0,0,36,AV,100612,161910,323227
```

Comment: Are you sure the csv is correct? You are showing us an Excel file (or at least a csv file opend with Excel which is fraught with danger) ... so what is the actual csv file contents?

Comment: Yes, I just opened it to give a better view to the reader.

Comment: Open it with a text editor... (and paste contents ... images are not generally welcome at SO).

Comment: Its the same data

Comment: It *can't* be , @Will . Excel doesn't display delimiters for a start. Also your first image of code ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) shows the value `06:13` but Excel has `6:13`; those are *not* the same either.

Comment: Aside from the errors that code is scary. It is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: I've edited to show the csv from a text editor. It's the same file.

Comment: Happy to take some guidance Sean.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Where does the value for TableName come from? Allowing the csv to determine which columns get data entered seems a bit odd to me but I can see where that could happen. What happens when there is a column defined in the CSV that doesn't exist in your table? Or just a typo?

Comment: @Larnu has hit the nail on the head. The source data doesn't have all the trailing commas so your assumption `line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','")` doesn't hold true when there aren't 11 crew members. You have a curious CSV format. It's sort of quote delimited as shown by AC_TYPE, I think? but inconsistently. I would expect that the end of line 2 would be a series of commas like `,323227,,,,,,,` etc until we hit all the crew members. With only 2 lines of data, it's challenging to say how you need to guard against bad/inconsistent data beyond the points the rest of the commenters have made.

Comment: The table name is from a variable. 

If there is a column provided which isn't in the table the package should fail and I will setup the error handling to email the relevant person.

Comment: The CSV file really should have *every* column defined. If the last columns are empty, they should still be represented, as @billinkc suggests. The problem is the CSV file. Very likely you need that addressed and then you can simply use a flat file manager with a "normal" Flat File Source in a Data Flow, rather than (ab)using a Script Task/Component (this looks like a Task to me). At least if you switched to a Component, you could likely avoid the massive injection flaw Sean references (but you still need that file fixed).

Comment: billinkc, larnu ... I will take this back to the person that passed me this file and see what they say. Thanks for raising it, somehow I hadn't spotted that.

Comment: This is why reviewing the text file in a text editor is important, @Will . Excel is a ***terrible*** application for doing such things, it can, and *will* make multiple *wrong* assumptions about the file, and can even end up completely breaking the data if you (are foolish enough) to save the file from the application.

Comment: As an example, I had to end up going to our Network Administrator to deny anyone but a few *trusted* member of IT access to write in a folder, as when users were reviewing some CSV files they kept opening them in Excel, and then saving the file afterwards; this resulted in things like phone numbers being stored as `1.234568E+09` rather than `01234567890`; making the data *completely* useless.

Comment: Fair point, well made.

We have had import problems before with the "to the power of" calculations in excel. Fortunately we found the excel save offender.

Comment: Since you are going back to making file change requests, you should ask for Json instead, or at a minimum ask for one crew members column with a different delimiter like '~'. Those crew members should be linked to the flight in a subtable and not crew1 thru 11

Comment: Only downside to json is the lack of support within SSIS - unless you GAC the newtonsoft library on all the machines that need to run the package.

Comment: @billinkc Is using System.Text.Json.Serialization; not available in SSIS yet? It's been a while. I would handle Json with a Console app usually so that I could handle other needed components like WebClient for APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I implemented in the end avoided the script task completely. Also meaning no SQL Injection possibilities.

I've done a flat file import. Everything into one column then using split_string and a pivot in SQL then inserted into a staging table before tidy up and off into main.

Flat File Import to single column table -> SQL transform -> Load

This also allowed me to iterate through the files better using a foreach loop container.

ELT on this occasion.

Thanks for all the help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Not touching the potential for sql injection as I'm free handing this code. If this a system generated file (Mainframe extract, dump from Dynamics or LoB app) the probability for sql injection is awfully low.

```
// Char required
char FileDelimiterChar = FileDelimiter.ToChar()[0];
int columnCount = 0;
while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        ColumnList = "[" + line.Replace(FileDelimiterChar, "],[") + "]";
        // How many columns in line 1. Assumes no embedded commas
        // The following assumes FileDelimiter is of type char
        // Add 1 as we will have one fewer delimiters than columns
        columnCount = line.Count(x => x == FileDelimiterChar) +1;
    }
    else
    {
        string query = "Insert into " + TableName + " (" + ColumnList + ") ";
        // HACK: this fails if there are embedded delimiters
        int foundDelimiters = line.Count(x => x == FileDelimiter) +1;
        // at this point, we know how many delimiters we have
        // and how many we should have.
        string csv = line.Replace(FileDelimiterChar, "','");

        // Pad out the current line with empty strings aka ','
        // Note: I may be off by one here
        // Probably a classier linq way of doing this or string.Concat approach
        for (int index = foundDelimiters; index <= columnCount; index++)
        {
             csv += "','";
        }

        query += "VALUES('" + csv + "')";

        // MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());

        SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, ADO_DB_Connection);
        myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    counter++;
}
```

Something like that should get you a solid shove in the right direction. The concept is that you need to inspect the first line and see how many columns you *should* have. Then for each line of data, how many columns do you *actually* have and then stub in the empty string.

If you change this up to use SqlCommand objects and parameters, the approximate logic is still the same. You'll add all the expected parameters by figuring out columns in the first line and then for each line you will add your values and if you have a short row, you just send the empty string (or dbnull or whatever your system expects).

The big take away IMO is that CSV parsing libraries exist for a reason and there are so many cases not addressed in the above psuedocode that you'll likely want to trash the current approach in favor of a standard parsing library and then while you're at it, address the potential security flaws.

I see your updated comment that you'll take the formatting concerns back to the source party. If they can't address them, I would envision your SSIS package being

Script Task -> Data Flow task.

Script Task is going to wrangle the unruly data into a strict CSV dialect that a Data Flow task can handle. Preprocessing the data into a new file instead of trying to modify the existing in place.

The Data Flow then becomes a chip shot of Flat File Source -> OLE DB Destination

Comment: I can't get the column count function working as the FileDelimiter is string. The operator == doesn't apply. Do you know how I could get round that? - No luck with the file creators.

Comment: Then you'll need to get a character version of the FileDelimiter variable. I added what I think is a sample of how you can convert a string to char but that's an easily searchable conversion if I buggered it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can process this file... I would still ask for Json or XML though.

You need two outputs set up. Flight Info (the 1st 16 columns) and Flight Crew (a business key [flight number and date maybe] and CrewID).

Seems to me the problem is how the crew is handled in the CSV.

So basic steps are Read the file, use regex to split it, write out first 16 col to output1 and the rest (with key) to flight crew. And skip the header row on your read.

```
var lines = System.File.IO.ReadAllLines("filepath");
for(int i =1; i<lines.length; i++)
{
    var = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("new Regex("(?:^|,)(?=[^\"]|(\")?)\"?((?(1)(?:[^\"]|\"\")*|[^,\"]*))\"?(?=,|$)"); //Some code I stole to split quoted CSVs
    var m = r.Matches(line[i]); //Gives you all matches in a MatchCollection
    //first 16 columns are always correct
    OutputBuffer0.AddRow();
    OutputBuffer0.Date = m[0].Groups[2].Value;
    OutputBuffer0.FlightNumber = m[1].Groups[2].Value;
    [And so on until m[15]]
    for(int j=16; j<m.Length; j++)
    {
         OutputBuffer1.AddRow(); //This is a new output that you need to set up
         OutputBuffer1.FlightNumber = m[1].Groups[2].Value;
         [Keep adding to make a business key here]
         OutputBuffer1.CrewID = m[j].Groups[2].Value;
    }
}
```

Be careful as I just typed all this out to give you a general plan without any testing. For example m[0] might actually be m[0].Value and all of the data types will be strings that will need to be converted.

To check out how regex processes your rows, please visit https://regex101.com/r/y8Ayag/1 for explanation. You can even paste in your row data.

**UPDATE:**
I just tested this and it works now. Needed to escape the regex function. And specify that you wanted the value of group 2. Also needed to hit IO in the File.ReadAllLines.